# Can $\{\Bbb R, [0, 1],\varnothing\}$ form a topology on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

I realise this is a very easy question. But it seems to me that from the standard (open sets) definition of a topology ($X$ and $\varnothing$ open, closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections) that the collection $\{\Bbb R, [0, 1], \varnothing\}$ forms a topology on $\mathbb R$. Why is this not the case?

Also, can someone point me in the direction of a good proof for why an open set in a topology does not contain it's boundary points (a proof from the axioms of a topology not from the concept of an open set in a metric space).

Comment: What makes you think it's not a topology?

Comment: After your most recent revision of the question, what you have is a topology.

Comment: That's what I thought, I think I was just thrown by the examples of topologies on R induced by metrics.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help

Answer (score 4):

$\{\mathbb R,[0,1],\varnothing\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb R$. Also, an open set may contain its boundary; for example, $\mathbb R$ itself. This uses the definition that the boundary of a set is the intersection of its closure and the closure of its complement, so that the boundary of $\mathbb R$ is $\varnothing$.

Comment: This, of course, depends on the definition of "boundary point."  The one I've seen is that $p$ is in the boundary of a set $U$ if every open set containing $p$ contains both points of $U$ and points not in $U$.  By this definition, an open set can not contain any boundary points, for if $p\in U$, with $U$ open, then $U$ itself witnesses the fact that $p$ is *not* in the boundary.

Comment: (Your definition doesn't avoid the issue I mentioned.  If $U$ is open and $p\in U$, then $U^c$ is closed, so is its own closure, and $p\notin U^c$, so $p$ is not a boundary point.  Also, perhaps I should say I'm worrying about the case when the boundary is nonempty, for if its empty, $U$ automatically contains *all* those points!)

Comment: Fair enough, I'll delete all these comments in a minute.  You may want to include a note about how this is the *only* way an open set can contain its boundary:  If the boundary is nonempty, an open set *never* contains any of the boundary points.